# Python rsync script directory names mirror

Tags: python, linux, rsync

I have a script that i use to push files back to my home PC using rsync. File names successfully pushed are added to a sqlite database so they don't get pushed again ( since i only want 1 way mirror ). Anyhow, the problem that i have is that although the script recursively goes down the source path and push files based on a defined extension, the files go down the same destination root directory.

What i am trying to is to have the destination folder structure the same as the source.

I think i have to do add something to the destDir path, but not exactly sure what:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sourceDir):
   for file in files:
     //If some filtering criteria
     print("Syncing new file: "+file)
     cmd=["rsync"]
     cmd.append(os.path.join(root, file))
     cmd.append(destDir+ "/")
     p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=False)
 if p.wait()==0:
  rememberFile(file)
```

Comment: I don't get it, why are you calling rsync iteratively on individual files, rather than on the sourceDir?  If they're already in the destination, they won't get pushed again - that's the whole point of rsync.

Comment: try http://www.rsnapshot.org/ (a higher level interface)

Comment: @wim: One way mirror, i want to push the files only once. I want to be able to move / delete / the files at the destination.

Comment: Using the --relative switch sorta works, but it puts the source directory into in the root of the destination: ( `python push.py ./a/ ./b/` creates a folder names a inside of b, instead of having the root files on a in the root of b

Comment: This issue (undesired subdirectory `a` inside `b`) is usually due to a trailing slash on either the source or destination. Hard to say exactly what is going on since your code adds a slash anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should rely on the features of `rsync` for this as much as possible, rather than trying to reimplement it in Python. `rsync` has been extensively tested and is full-featured. They've fixed all of the bugs that you're encountering. For instance, in your original code snippet, you need to reconstruct the full path of your file (instead of just the filename) and add that to your `destDir`.

But before you keep debugging that, consider this alternative. Instead of a sql db, why not keep all of the files that you have pushed in a plain text file? Let's say it's called `exclude_list.txt`. Then your one-liner rsync command is:

```
rsync -r --exclude-from 'exclude_list.txt' src dst
```

The `-r` switch will cause it to traverse the file tree automatically. See [topic #6 on this page](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/) for more details on this syntax.

Now you only need your Python script to maintain `exclude_list.txt`. I can think of two options:

- Capture the output of `rsync` with the `-v` option to list the filenames that were moved, parse them, and append to `exclude_list.txt`. I think this is the most elegant solution. You can probably do it in just a few lines.
- Use the script you already have to traverse the tree and add all of the files to `exclude_list.txt`, but remove all of the individual `rsync` calls. Then call `rsync` once at the end, as above.

Comment: mmmm i see what you are saying. But for what i want to do, i think i would need to implement both your suggestions: I need to traverse first to generate / append to exclude.txt the files that i don't want based on filter ( .exe, .doc, etc ) then sync the rest. Once that is done, rsync the rest and as you mentioned, capture the verbose output and parse that way. Any suggestion on how about doing that?  Would be looking for specific string ("Successful") and add what follows?

Comment: EDIT: It seems that i can use wildcards in the exclude list, so i don't have to traverse first to filter on extension, i can just do that in the exclude file.

Comment: Yes, I would probably use -v and --log-file arguments to `rsync` to dump the list of transferred files, then parse that log file with python. You'll have to do some tests to make sure it will still work if `rsync` fails, for instance due to an unmounted destination.